# Google Sheets - Query within query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got 3 major sheets:

```
Group Permission: Database of permissions and levels
Profile Config: Profile settings of which groups and levels which profile will inherit
Result: A database query to show only what would be the result if the profile displayed on B1 is chosen
```

I was trying to query from database all rows that match group, permissions and level specified on Profile Config.

The thing is: if the profile is granted permission level 2 it will grab level 1's as well, and so forth.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u4umE7qKxHOtQ8KfbafuSPHt25rTtzas/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115849945160804839689&rtpof=true&sd=true

The formula on **Result!A3** I came with was:

```
=QUERY('Group Permission'!A$2:G,"select A,C,F,G,D,E where (F like in ('"&QUERY('Profile Config'!A$2:D;"select C where (C IS NOT NULL) and (A like '"&B1&"')";0)&"') and(G <= '"&'Profile Config'!B$2:D&"')";0)
```

Comment: Please supply an example of the expected outcome. Also, "Profile Config", Column D are a combination of text and numbers - they should be one or the other.

Comment: `The thing is: if the profile is granted permission level 2 it will grab level 1's as well, and so forth.` It is not clear whether that is a statement of intent, or a complaint. I _do_ note that the Profile Config for Group="Client Supplier"=>Permission=4, but on "Group Permissions", the same Group has permission of null or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.  In short, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. This seems like the right time to ask you to describe, in words, the goal of your formula, and to remind you that you need to supply an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Thank you for you questions, @Tedinoz. 
Although 'rockinfreakshow gave me a precise answer that solved my problem I owe you an apropriate follow up.'

When selecting one option from B1's list the result would be something like they achieved in the image.

Furthermore I didn't get how is 'Profile Config'!D column would be a combination of text and numbers.

Comment: @Tedinoz 
About the comment of whether it was a statement of intent or complaint, the former.
I was trying to say that the higher levels always got the lower levels' permission as well.
Again, I'm sorry I didn't provide sufficient data to display the desired outcome.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It could be very helpful for future users who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution you can try out:

```
=let(data_,filter({'Profile Config'!C:D},'Profile Config'!A:A=B1),Λ,'Group Permission'!A:G,grp_,index(data_,,1),lvl_,index(data_,,2),
     Σ,reduce(wraprows(,6,),sequence(counta(grp_)),lambda(a,c,{a;sort(ifna(filter(choosecols(Λ,1,3,6,7,4,5),choosecols(Λ,6)=index(grp_,c),--choosecols(Λ,7)<=--index(lvl_,c)),wraprows(,6,)),4,)})),
     filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to order the outcome by ascending PermCode?

Comment: there's already `sort` function used in the formula with Column **4** `Level` as parameter You can change it to Column **5** `PermCode`. Right now its `sort(--formula--,4,)` Change it to `sort(--formula--,5,1)`

Comment: Sorry to bother you, @rockinafreakshow.
I noticed that Result was showing mixed values because there are identical Permission names between different Systems. What I think will solve it is adding SysCode before Group in Profile Config and in Result the formula will use it as criteria to query values. What do I need to change to achieve this new condition?

Comment: Never mind. I scooped through the code, found out what those functions did and found out I had to create another variable on LET that refered to the new column I inserted and then, on the second filter function, adding another parameter that used this new column.